# How to find intervals of the inequality $ \sqrt[4]\frac{5+3\cdot\cos(4x)}{8} > -\cos(x) $?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality, trigonometry

I have the following inequality:
$$
\sqrt[4]\frac{5+3\cdot\cos(4x)}{8} > -\cos(x)
$$

And the following solution:
\begin{align} 
\frac{5 + 3 \cdot \cos(4x)}{8} &< \cos^4(x) \\
5 + 3 \cdot \cos(4x) &< 8 \cdot \cos^4(x) \\
5 + 3 \cdot \cos(4x) - 8 \cdot \cos^4(x) &< 0 \\
5 + 3(2\cos^2(2x) - 1) 
- 8\biggl( \frac{1 + 2\cos(2x) + \cos^2(2x)}{4} \biggr) &< 0 \\
5 + 6 \cdot \cos^2(2x) - 3 - 2 - 4\cos(2x) - 2\cos^2(2x) &< 0 \\
6\cos^2(2x) - 4\cos(2x) - 2\cos^2(2x) &< 0 \\
4\cos^2(2x) - 4\cos(2x) &< 0
\end{align}

But it is not clear for me what to do next. How can I finish this inequality?

Comment: Hint: You can factor $4\cos(2x)$ out of both terms. This is a quadratic inequality in the variable $u=\cos(2x)$.

Comment: I understand your point, but I still can't understand what's going to be next...

$$4cos(2x)(cos(2x) - 1) < 0$$

Something like this?
$$4cos(2x) < 0$$
$$cos(2x) < 1$$

Comment: Not quite. I'll say more in an answer.

Comment: By the way, use `\cos` to set cosine as an operator in a roman typeface.

Comment: @SammyBlack, ok, thanks! Also thank you for editing my question

Answer (score 0):

The solution to a quadratic inequality $au^2 + bu + c < 0$, where $p(u)$ has two real roots, is either an interval or its complement (two disjoint rays). In other words, it's either the real numbers between the roots or the real numbers outside of the roots. It depends on the sign of $a$. Picture a parabola and when it's on one side of the $u$-axis or the other.

In your case, you have $4u(u - 1) < 0$ or equivalently $u(u - 1) < 0$. Since this polynomial has a positive leading coefficient, the solution set will consist of all $u$ such that $0 < u < 1$. In terms of the original variable $x$, this looks like
$$
0 < \cos(2x) < 1.
$$

Treating $2x$ as an indivisible quantity satisfying $0 < 2x < 4\pi$ for the moment, we find that the argument of cosine must satisfy live on one of the open intervals
$$
\bigl( 0, \tfrac{\pi}{2} \bigr) \cup 
\bigl( \tfrac{3\pi}{2}, 2\pi \bigr) \cup
\bigl( 2\pi, \tfrac{5\pi}{2} \bigr) \cup 
\bigl( \tfrac{7\pi}{2}, 4\pi \bigr). 
$$
Finally, dividing these inequalities by $2$, we find that $x$ lies on
$$
\bigl( 0, \tfrac{\pi}{4} \bigr) \cup 
\bigl( \tfrac{3\pi}{4}, \pi \bigr) \cup
\bigl( \pi, \tfrac{5\pi}{4} \bigr) \cup 
\bigl( \tfrac{7\pi}{4}, 2\pi \bigr). 
$$
Of course adding any integer multiple of $2\pi$ to a solution in one of those intervals yields another solution, due to the periodicity of the trig functions. Here are the graphs of $y = 5 + 3\cos(4x)$ and $y = \cos^4(x)$ on the same axis, where you can see the inequality satisfied on those periodic intervals.

[image: Sinusoids to compare.]

Answer (score 0):

The inequality$$\sqrt[4]\frac{5+3\cos(4x)}8>-\cos(x)\qquad\color{blue}{(*)}$$is equivalent to

$\cos(x)>0\quad\lor\quad\begin{cases}\cos(x)\leqslant0\\[5pt]\dfrac{5+3\cos(4x)}8>\cos^4(x)\end{cases}$

which is equivalent to

$\cos(x)>0\quad\lor\quad\begin{cases}\cos(x)\leqslant0\\[5pt]4\cos^2(2x)-4\cos(2x)>0\end{cases}$

which is equivalent to

$\cos(x)>0\quad\lor\quad\begin{cases}\cos(x)\leqslant0\\[5pt]\cos(2x)<0\end{cases}\;.$

The solutions of $\;\cos(x)>0\;$ are :

$S_1=\bigcup\limits_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left\{\left[2k\pi,\dfrac\pi2\!+\!2k\pi\!\right)\bigcup\left(\!\dfrac{3\pi}2\!+\!2k\pi,2\pi\!+\!2k\pi\!\right)\right\}.$

The solutions of $\;\cos(x)\leqslant0\;$ are :

$S_2=\bigcup\limits_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left[\dfrac\pi2\!+\!2k\pi,\dfrac{3\pi}2\!+\!2k\pi\right].$

The solutions of $\;\cos(2x)<0\;$ are :

$S_3=\bigcup\limits_{k\in\Bbb Z}\!\left\{\left(\!\dfrac\pi4\!+\!2k\pi,\dfrac{3\pi}4\!+\!2k\pi\!\right)\bigcup\left(\!\dfrac{5\pi}4\!+\!2k\pi,\dfrac{7\pi}4\!+\!2k\pi\!\right)\right\}.$

Hence, the solutions of the inequality $\,(*)\,$ are :

$S=S_1\bigcup\left(S_2\bigcap S_3\right)=\\=\bigcup\limits_{k\in\Bbb Z}\left\{\left[2k\pi,\dfrac{3\pi}4\!+\!2k\pi\!\right)\bigcup\left(\!\dfrac{5\pi}4\!+\!2k\pi,2\pi\!+\!2k\pi\!\right)\right\}.$